# Android AsyncTask is not working

Tags: android

I got error on  `onPreExecute()'

See my code : 
I have confuse here(
download method (loadDailyDownloadData)contain in the  different class & calling `AsyncTask` is different class...)

```
public class ListRoutesActivity extends Activity {

 public void onNextAction(View view){
    if(selectedRoutes.size() > 0){
        StringBuffer routeCode = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0; i<selectedRoutes.size();i++){
            routeCode.append("\'" + selectedRoutes.get(i) +"\'" +",");
        }
        routeCode.delete(routeCode.length() - 1,routeCode.length());
        strUField1 = routeCode.toString();
        new DailyDownldAsyncTask().execute();
    //  String s = new DownlaodTableActivity().loadDailyDownloadData(strBusinessUnit, strExecutive,strTerritoryCode,strUField1);
    //  System.out.println(" ---s - " + s);

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(ListRoutesActivity.this,"Please select the Route!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
     return;
 }



     public class DailyDownldAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
         private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ListRoutesActivity.this);
         int myProgress;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            System.out.println(" ---- result--- " + result);
            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            }
            Toast.makeText(ListRoutesActivity.this,"Download successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {

          this.dialog.setMessage("Downloading Table Data.......");
          this.dialog.show();
          myProgress = 0;
      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
          return  new DownlaodTableActivity().loadDailyDownloadData(strBusinessUnit, strExecutive,strTerritoryCode,strUField1);

      }

      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
          dialog.setProgress(values[0]);
      }
 }}
```

Here is my logcat :

```
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     ... 11 more
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@4054c798 is not valid; is your activity running?
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:527)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at com.xont.controller.admin.ListRoutesActivity$DailyDownldAsyncTask.onPreExecute(ListRoutesActivity.java:164)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at com.xont.controller.admin.ListRoutesActivity.onNextAction(ListRoutesActivity.java:100)
08-19 17:45:18.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     ... 14 more
```

**Without AsynTask my functionality is working fine** that mean if I call `new DownlaodTableActivity().loadDailyDownloadData(strBusinessUnit, strExecutive,strTerritoryCode,strUField1);` this method directly without AsynTask , Its working fine

Please Help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems, your `DownlaodTableActivity()` is indeed not running. You can't start an activity but just instantiating it, you need to call `startActivity(Intent)`, passing the `Intent` for the activity you want to start. 
However, your code looks weird. The `DownlaodTableActivity().loadDailyDownloadData(strBusinessUnit, strExecutive,strTerritoryCode,strUField1);` method can be placed in a class that doesn't extend activity, then you'll have no problems. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks , I got little clear on this... But error message on ' @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
    this.dialog.setMessage("Downloading Table Data.......");
    this.dialog.show();
       myProgress = 0;
   }'  here.Is it?

Comment: @Nagkeeran Piraba, Your logcat clearly states that you're trying to execute a method of an activity that is not currently running.